# Cannot get new pages with FB graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have generated a user access token with `pages_show_list` permission.
Everything works fine for existing pages, but api does not return information for newly created pages (which I created after generating token).

[image: Pages list]

Comment: Heard this before, I think that might be a “feature” Facebook introduced deliberately. Try to log out of the app and then login again. If that doesn’t work, try and explicitly remove the permission first, then login again.

Comment: @misorude Yes, removing permissions and then logging in again fixes the problem, but I don't think it's a good solution

Comment: Please check this link. https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/347345726022992/