# not getting new facebook page in page list using FB apis

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have created new facebook page and now trying to fetch the page list. But I am getting new page in my list.

Api I am using below:-

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/me/accounts?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&user_id=xxx

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/52889519/10283047

Comment: This is a current bug. Remove the page managing permission via your account’s Facebook settings, login & grant it again, then you should see the new page show up as well.