# FB Graph API Exception Status: : The 'manage_pages' permission must be granted before impersonating a user's page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I get the following response using the FB Graph API like so:

Request:
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/someId123/insights/page_impressions_unique/day?since={date.add(-90).format()}&until={date.today}

Rersponse:
Service responded with exception status (400): {"error":{"message":"The 'manage_pages' permission must be granted before impersonating a user's page.","type":"OAuthException","code":190,"fbtrace_id":"abc123"}}

This happens even though I have site admin rights and weirdly enough only with some pages while others work just fine.

How can I check that I indeed (don't) have 'mange_pages' rights?

Comment: There’s a current bug with pages that the user was made an admin of after they granted the permission, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/52903989/10283047 Try to remove the permission from your Facebook account app settings, and grant it again on next login.

Comment: I removed and added the page permissions for one page, but so still get the 400

Comment: Not sure how you managed to get that error message in the first place. This requires a page access token to begin with, using any other kind of token should only get you a message saying so; but without `manage_pages` permission, you could not _have_ a page access token in the first place …