# Facebook Pages loose permissions when adding a new Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am an admin of multiple Facebook pages. I also have a Facebook app that has amongst others manage_pages permission for these pages (it is used as part of an chat integration that reads messages from these pages). I encountered an unexpected behaviour when creating a new page. When adding permissions to this new page, all my existing pages seem to have lost their permissions.

When checking my active business integrations, i can see all my pages and can see that the permissions, such as manage_pages are unticked.

Also when obtaining the page access token for one of the pages, i get the following error message `The 'manage_pages' permission must be granted before impersonating a user's page.`

I looked at existing [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52929469/fb-graph-api-exception-status-the-manage-pages-permission-must-be-granted-b) answers, but they deal with permissions of new pages not being inherited rather than permissions of existing pages being lost

I'd expect that adding a new page does not have any effect on my other pages. Did anybody else run into the same problem? Is this a known Facebook bug?

Comment: Explain what exactly _“When adding permissions to this new page”_ means.

Comment: Apologies i should clarify: Our integration retrieves page access tokens for a page with a set of permissions. It does this by going through an authorization flow. In this flow it will ask the admin of the page for the set of permissions